# Error couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: postgresql, docker, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

While installing **Nginx** controller, getting below error for **Kubernetes** initialisation.
I am using Postgres for DB
"error execution phase wait-control-plane:error couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster"

Log : Job k8s-ctrl-init failed to complete

Comment: where is the error logs?

Comment: Thanks, I checked it in log file and there was an error in database access, This has been fixed now.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to add logs and answer it with the solution

Comment: Please edit your question according to StackOverflow rules https://stackoverflow.com/tour . Also can you paste configuration files and tutorial used during setup ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorted. It was a k8s problem, some files didn't init correctly, so I just deleted and re-installed Nginx controller.